# How to ask for user input and return it in a new inventory

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit

I am 13, so please do not get impatient with me here as I might be making a dumb mistake or not thinking something in the right perspective.

I want to make a Spigot plugin to increase my Java knowledge a little bit, by making a project that is fun and educational. I'm following a tutorial on how to make a GUI, but wanted to create it with a twist that is not too complex.

I was poking around and found something that is similar to show an example of this [LobbyCompass](https://dev.bukkit.org/projects/lobbycompass).

Here is my "GuiConstruct" class

```
import org.bukkit.Bukkit;
import org.bukkit.ChatColor;
import org.bukkit.inventory.Inventory;

public class GuiConstruct {

    private String input(String input) {
        return input;
    }


    public Inventory newGui(String Name, int size) {
        return Bukkit.getServer().createInventory(null,9, ChatColor.RED + input());
    }

}
```

Here is my main class

```
package me.yarkosharko.worldswitcher;

import org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin;

public final class WorldSwitcher extends JavaPlugin {

    @Override
    public void onEnable() {
        // Plugin startup logic

    }

    @Override
    public void onDisable() {
        // Plugin shutdown logic
    }
}
```

Am I thinking of this the right way? Do I have to do something entirely different? Just to be clear I want to make something like this:

/worldswitcher 'args'

then it shows an inventory GUI with the name 'args'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I maybe didn't understand your question, as it wasn't straight-forward. As I get it, you want to create command that opens up a GUI with specified name. There are multiple ways to do that... The simplest way is to implement method `onCommand` in plugin main class.

```java
public final class WorldSwitcher extends JavaPlugin {

    @Override
    public void onEnable() {
        // Plugin startup logic

    }

    @Override
    public void onDisable() {
        // Plugin shutdown logic
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command command, String label,String[] args) {
        // executor must be player
        if(!(sender instanceof Player)) {
            sender.sendMessage("§cYou must be player to execute this command!");
            return true;
        }
        
        // If command name is "worldswitcher", handle logic
        if(command.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("worldswitcher")) {
            // If an argument is present, we can work with it
            if(args.length > 0){
                // cast player from command sender
                Player executor = (Player) commandSender;
                // get first argument
                String worldName = args[0];
                // openup a gui for him
                MyGUIClass.openGui(executor, worldName/*, other parameters*/)
            
            } else {
                // we require single argument, but it is missing
                sender.sendMessage("§cMissing argument");
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

And you must add this to your plugin.yml

```yaml
commands:
    worldswitcher: {}
```

This code maybe explains how it works, but if not there are a lot of great resources for learning how commands work: [Tutorial from TheSourceCode: CommandExecutors](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SaEqn0wpL40), [Tutorial from Pogostick(Noah Rubin): Basic commands](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bVySbfryiMM&list=PLAF3anQEEkzREsHA8yZzVhc3_GHcPnqxR)

Comment: Thank you, and can I also have help on this part:

                ExampleGui.openGui(executor, worldName);

            } else {
                // we require single argument, but it is missing
                sender.sendMessage("§cMissing argument");
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}

Whenever I type "/worldswitcher 'args' " it says
Missing Argument
Any Ideas? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: well clearly, the argument count is zero... you can check argument count by simply printing `args.length` to console. `if(args.length > 0)` is the failing statement.